# React Native -- FlatList data updated but Render Item does not when data changed

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-native-flatlist, asyncstorage

I am using a FlatList in which I am using a single component on two pages. One is home and next is Favourites. My issue is this I have created a poll card in which when a user submit an answer to the poll then both list must be updated based on list data changed. I have saved the list in context and changing the values in array from context but my card values not updated.

**FlatList Code (Feed.js)**

```
const { feedArray,setFeedArray} = useContext(AuthContext);

<FlatList
          extraData={feedArray}
          data={feedArray}
          renderItem={({item, index}) => (
            <RenderCard
              item={item}
              navigation={navigation}
              index={index}
              managePost={false}
              isPaymentReport={false}
              isBookmark={false}
              previewMode={false}
              isPinnedPost={false}
              isPaymentExplorer={false}
            />
          )}
          numColumns={1}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
          contentContainerStyle={{
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
          }}
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
          keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled"
          onEndReachedThreshold={0.05}
          onScrollBeginDrag={() => setLoadingMore(true)}
          onEndReached={handleOnEndReached}
          ListFooterComponent={() => loadingMore && <ListFooterComponent />}
          refreshControl={
            <RefreshControl
              refreshing={refreshing}
              onRefresh={() => onRefresh()}
              tintColor={Colors.light.black}
            />
          }
        />
```

**Poll Card Code (Poll.js)**

**On Button Pressed to submit Poll**

```
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={updateSurveyCard}>Submit</TouchableOpacity>
```

**Update Survey Card with submitted option**

```
      const updateSurveyCard = value => {

        let newArray = feedArray;

       const index = newArray.findIndex(object => {
       return object.cardId === item.cardId;
       });

        if (index !== -1) {
         newArray[index].surveyArray = [{"percentage": 100, "response": "F"},     {"percentage": "0", "response": "T"}];
         } 

          setFeedArray([... newArray]);

      }
```

but the issue is that when I change this data and set in setFeedArray again the my feedArray called again and I am able to get all the list on Feed.js but my Poll.js has not updated with latest data. I want to updated "surveyArray" with lates values on Poll.js

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Try to store data in useState();

```
const [feedArray,setFeedArray] = useState(AuthContext);
```

Comment: But I need to use this feedArray every where in app that's why I have used context.

Comment: Then try to save data in AsynStorage the just retrieve it wherever you want.
This blog will help you with AsynStorage: https://blog.logrocket.com/guide-react-natives-asyncstorage/